# filter an array from another array each content

Tags: arrays, filter, find

i've encountered some problem in Array.

`firstArray = [ eva, ema, ela] secondArray = [(Name:eva , Done: 2), (Name:ela , Done: 5), (Name:ema , Done: 3), (Name:ela , Done: 1), (Name:ema , Done: 0), (Name:eva , Done: 4), (Name:ela , Done: 6), (Name:ema , Done: 8), (Name:eva , Done: 7), (Name:ela , Done: 9)]`

ok, so what I want is, we get the first element from firstArray then filter the secondArray .Then continue with the second element from firstArray, until third Element of firstArray.

Output that I want
`[(name:eva , [Done : 2, 4, 7]) , (name:ema , [Done : 3, 0, 8]) , (name:ela , [Done : 5, 1, 9]) ]`

Hope to find a solution, TQ in advance.

i tried

`for( var n = 0; n<firstArray.length; n++){ const filter = secondArray.filter(e=> e.Name ==  firstArray[n] }`

Comment: What language is that supposed to be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways of achieving that output. Since you haven't mentioned language, I've provided a similar example in javascript. you can make similar changes in another language also. One of the ways of doing this in javascript is as follows:

```
let a = ["eva", "ema", "ela"];
let b = [
  { Name: "eva", Done: 2 },
  { Name: "ela", Done: 5 },
  { Name: "ema", Done: 3 },
  { Name: "ela", Done: 1 },
  { Name: "ema", Done: 0 },
  { Name: "eva", Done: 4 },
  { Name: "ela", Done: 6 },
  { Name: "ema", Done: 8 },
  { Name: "eva", Done: 7 },
  { Name: "ela", Done: 9 },
];


let c = a.map((eachA) => {
    return b.filter((eachB) => eachA === eachB.Name)
}).map((eachC) => {
    return {
        Name : eachC.at(0).Name,
        Done: eachC.map((e) => e.Done)
    }
})

console.log(c)

Output : 
[
    { Name: 'eva', Done: [ 2, 4, 7 ] },
    { Name: 'ema', Done: [ 3, 0, 8 ] },
    { Name: 'ela', Done: [ 5, 1, 6, 9 ] }
]
```